# Razor if else only TR tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

What is wrong with following Razor code.
I would like to have a different  tag depending on a certain condition.
But i cant seem to get it right.
i've tried a lot of possibilities, but some help would be nice.

```
@helper DrawTableRow(GameModel item)
{
    if (true)
    {
        @:<tr class="type1">
    }
    else
    {
        @:<tr class="type2">
    }

        <td>@item.Name</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a solution, but i fixed what i needed in another way

```
<tr @if (Model.GameDetailsModel != null) { @: style="cursor: pointer" onclick="location.href = @Model.GameDetailsModel.Url?Id=@item.Id"
}>
```

so basically i did not create the if else with each a tr tag, i just created one tr tag and just put an if inside the tr

Answer (score 0):

You can't use  in if statement like that:

```
if (true)
{
  <tr class="table-primary">
}
```

It dosn't work becouse don't have close  tag.
But you can make new string with name of class you want to use.

```
@if (yourConditionIsTrue)
{ 
  string @classString = "table-primary";
}
else
{
  string @classString = "";
}
```

then you use that string in class of

```
 <tr class="@classString">
// when condition is true will be:
// <tr class="table-primary">
// when condition is false will be:
// <tr class="">
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate on the answer? The part after Then is not clear

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).